# SonataUserBundle does not attempt to load any styles

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin, sonata-user-bundle

I've configured `SonataUserBundle` together with `SonataAdminBundle`. I now have access to URLs like /login, /register, /profile. This is how the login page looks like. Other pages also do not have any styles loaded.

[image]

Does Sonata provide any default styles for these pages. I though that maybe I have a problem with dependency version. This is 'Sonata' fragment of my `composer.json`:

```
    "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "~2.3",
    "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "^2.3",
    "sonata-project/easy-extends-bundle": "^2.1",
    "sonata-project/user-bundle": "^2.2",
    "knplabs/knp-menu": "~1.1",
    "knplabs/knp-menu-bundle": "~1.1",
    "sonata-project/core-bundle": "~2.3"
```

I've also installed the assets with `php app/console assets:install web --symlink`, cleared the cache with `php app/console cache:clear`.

When I inspect the 'Network' tab in the Chrome Dev tools, no asset files are ever attempted to be loaded.

I'd rather expect something like [this](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/user/master/doc/reference/user_dashboard.html).

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

You shall check first in your configuration with the reference one on the official documentation : 
https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/configuration.html

for the 2.3 version, you should have :

```
assets:
        stylesheets:

            # Defaults:
            - bundles/sonataadmin/vendor/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css
            - bundles/sonataadmin/vendor/AdminLTE/css/font-awesome.min.css
            - bundles/sonataadmin/vendor/AdminLTE/css/ionicons.min.css
            - bundles/sonataadmin/vendor/AdminLTE/css/AdminLTE.css
            - bundles/sonatacore/vendor/eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker/build/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css
            - bundles/sonataadmin/vendor/jqueryui/themes/base/jquery-ui.css
            - bundles/sonataadmin/vendor/select2/select2.css
            - bundles/sonataadmin/vendor/select2/select2-bootstrap.css
            - bundles/sonataadmin/vendor/x-editable/dist/bootstrap3-editable/css/bootstrap-editable.css
            - bundles/sonataadmin/css/styles.css
            - bundles/sonataadmin/css/layout.css
        javascripts:

            # Defaults:
            - bundles/sonataadmin/vendor/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js
            - bundles/sonataadmin/vendor/jquery.scrollTo/jquery.scrollTo.min.js
            - bundles/sonatacore/vendor/moment/min/moment.min.js
            - bundles/sonataadmin/vendor/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js
            - bundles/sonatacore/vendor/eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker/build/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js
            - bundles/sonataadmin/vendor/jqueryui/ui/minified/jquery-ui.min.js
            - bundles/sonataadmin/vendor/jqueryui/ui/minified/i18n/jquery-ui-i18n.min.js
            - bundles/sonataadmin/jquery/jquery.form.js
            - bundles/sonataadmin/jquery/jquery.confirmExit.js
            - bundles/sonataadmin/vendor/x-editable/dist/bootstrap3-editable/js/bootstrap-editable.min.js
            - bundles/sonataadmin/vendor/select2/select2.min.js
            - bundles/sonataadmin/App.js
            - bundles/sonataadmin/Admin.js
```

Comment: These seem to be default values that are in place anyway if you do not explicitly override them.